# Retrofit Body Annotation Data

Tags: android, post, annotations, retrofit

I was working with Retrofit library `@Body` annotation,

Created a interface:

```
interface Foo {

  @POST("/jayson")
  FooResponse postJson(@Body FooRequest body);

}
```

Created a model class:

```
public class FooRequest {
  final String foo;
  final String bar;

  FooRequest(String foo, String bar) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}
```

Created a request:

```
FooResponse = foo.postJson(new FooRequest("kit", "kat"));
```

Then I received response:

```
{
    "foo": "kit",
    "bar": "kat"
}
```

But what if I want to create a response like this:

```
{
    "foo": "kit",
    "bar": "kat",
    "obj": { 
        "id": "1"
    }
}
```

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create class field that represents the embedded response field:

```
class Embedded {
    final String id;
}

// The whole response
public class FooRequest {
  final String foo;
  final String bar;
  final Embedded obj;

  FooRequest(String foo, String bar, Embedded obj) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
    this.obj = obj;
  }
}
```

And this will be serialized to JSON as:

```
{
    "foo": "kit",
    "bar": "kat",
    "obj": {
        "id": "1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrii, and what about JSONArray ?

Comment: @AmratSingh it could be defined as `List<Embedded>` or `Embedded[]`. So the types are serialized logically. If it it a collection or array it will be a JSONArray

Comment: Problem Solved, Thanks Again @Andrii

Comment: @AmratSingh if you found this answer helpful, feel free to accept it. In this way, other will be sure that this solution works

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FooRequest {
  final String foo;
  final String bar;
  final Class object;

  FooRequest(String foo, String bar, Class object) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
    this.object = object;
  }
}
```

Create Class.java as :

```
public class Class
{
int id;

//setter getters for id
}

FooResponse = foo.postJson(new FooRequest("kit", "kat", class));
```

where class is object you set.

Comment: The field for embedded object should be string, as you can see in example JSON

Comment: its not necessary to be string objects can also be serialized and deserialized in json. If you want to store id as string just change datatype from int to String

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan Thanks

Comment: No problem @AmratSingh